# proxychains browser unable to download and open files

Tags: ubuntu, socks-proxy

Ubuntu 10.10, Midori 0.2.4 browser (same problem with Epiphany 2.30.2, haven't tried with Firefox or Chrome as yet)

Proxychains-3.1 installed, working fine.

Here is the deal: when *NOT* proxychained, Midori or Epiphany can download and open a file (e.g. PDFs from a Google search) in Evince without problem.

But when proxychained, neither browser can download or open PDF files. Even if I select "save" or "save as", the message is, "file xxx downloaded". But when I check the downloads folder, there is no file. Whats going on here?

I don't want to use FF or Chrome. Chrome does not follow my GTK2 customizations and FF is just too resource heavy. Please help.

Comment: UPDATE: updated to Midori 0.3.2. Now files can be saved to disk when proxychained, but still cannot be launched (opened).

Comment: One clue: when proxychained, Midori stores the temporary files in /tmp and is unable to open the files. When started normally, the files are downloaded to ~/Downloads and files can be opened in respective programs like Evince.

Comment: OK This is getting weird. Strike the above comment. Even when launched normally, the files are still downloaded to /tmp and are opened without problem. The question is, what happens when proxychainoed? It is not a permissions problem because in both cases files have the same permissions and ownership.